# Logging in JasperReports Scriptlet

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I want to do logging in a JasperReports scriptlet. I just wanted to know are there any Jasper Logs available?

I know that JasperReports uses Apache log4j for logging.

So are there any customized log API of JasperReports, or can I directly use Apache log4j API for logging in a JasperReports Scriptlet?

Also I saw that JasperReports uses slf4j facade to wrap log4j. Can I directly use slf4j API for logging?

Answer (score 0):

In chart customizers I have followed this standard pattern of using log4j directly. You should be able to do the same in a scriptlet:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
...
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BetterBarLabels.class);
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
  logger.debug("################## DEBUG info from BetterBarLabels ##################");
}
```